# Can’t install 19.04 from usb

Tags: system-installation

I’m struggling to install Ubuntu 19.04 from USB. It gets to the purple screen then:

[image]

and thereafter this

[image]

I have tried safe graphics install option and other grub options.

PC is new desktop with ryzen 3600x cpu, gigabyte b450 motherboard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installation failure on AMD Ryzen 3900X and Gigabyte Auros Master X570 motherboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161799/installation-failure-on-amd-ryzen-3900x-and-gigabyte-auros-master-x570-motherboa)